# how to store face_encodings

Tags: python, sql, database, face-recognition

```
encodings = face_recognition.face_encodings(rgb_img)[0]
```

I looked online, but I still can't find how to store the encodings in a database for quick retrieval and comparison to a given image.

This is the only code that I found for PostgreSQL cube, but it throws an error, plus I'm not sure whether it will be fast enough for a lookup.

```
if len(encodings) > 0:
    query = "INSERT INTO vectors (file, image_id, vec_low, vec_high) VALUES ('{}', {}, CUBE(array[{}]), CUBE(array[{}])) RETURNING id".format(
        remote_file_url,
        image_id,
        ','.join(str(s) for s in encodings[0][0:64]),
        ','.join(str(s) for s in encodings[0][64:128]),
    )
```

Also, found an article on ElasticSearch, but also not certain whether it can handle large number of images and is optimal for search: https://www.elastic.co/blog/how-to-build-a-facial-recognition-system-using-elasticsearch-and-python

Can someone recommend a solution please?